# Using a function passed as a paramter

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to write a function `nestedArrayMinWithRule` that finds the minimum value of a nested array, where the value also fits some criterion (the rule).
The function I have so far is

```
nestedArrayMinWithRule(data, rule): number {
    let minimum = Number.MAX_VALUE;
    for (const i of data) {
      for (const j of data) {
        minimum = (j < minimum && rule(j)) ? j : minimum;
      }
    }
    return minimum;
  }
```

It is being called elsewhere as follows:

```
minimum = nestedArrayMinWithRule(data, ((e) => e !== 0));
```

But from the results it seems like I am either not calling using `rule` properly in my function, or not defining it property when it is an argument to the function. I also tried separating the rule into its own value, as in:

```
const rule = ((e) => e !== 0));
minimum = nestedArrayMinWithRule(data, rule);
```

But this did not work either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what's in `data`... Could be there are no values that match the rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in your loops:

```
for (const i of data) {
  for (const j of data) {
    minimum = (j < minimum && rule(j)) ? j : minimum;
  }
}
```

I assume this should be:

```
for (const i of data) {
  for (const j of i) {
    minimum = (j < minimum && rule(j)) ? j : minimum;
  }
}
```

There's a few things that would have showed you that:

1. Step through debugging
2. Typescript
3. Linters that catch unused variables
4. Console.logging some of the variables

Comment: That is absolutely it. Thank you for catching my silly typo.